# How to convert mac osx dictionary to linux readable format?

Tags: linux, macos, dictionary, pandoc

I would like to be able to take the dictionary data described here:

http://priithaamer.com/blog/ruby-on-rails-dictionary-for-macosx

And convert it for reading on linux. Is there an app such as pandoc that can take these files as input:

http://f.priithaamer.com/dictionary/Ruby%20on%20Rails.dictionary.zip

And output something readable on linux in a similar fashion?

Comment: Could you incorporate some of the high level info from those links in your question? That way if those sites go away this question will still be relevant and able to stand on its own.

Comment: Just hit the guy who wrote the blog up and make him fix the link to the windows/linux version, which currently takes you to apple :P